# Удалить тег со страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Возникла проблема. 
При выполнении определенных условий  в скриптея я  создаю элемент и добавляю его в div

```
var video = "<video autoplay controls> <source src='" + sImgUri + "'type='video/mp4'>Your browser does not     support the video tag.</video>";
oArea.append(video);
```

И на странице у меня появляется вот такой вот элемнет

```
<div class="prod-img" style="background-image: none;">
  <video autoplay="" controls="">
  <source src="http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/H264/Talkinghead_Media/H264_test1_Talkinghead_mp4_480x360.mp4" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>
</div>
```

Далее я хочу  удалить тэг  вместе с содержимым.

Делаю это вот так:

```
$(".prod-img video").remove();
```

Но ничего не происходит.

Может кто-нибудь подскажет, каким способом можно удалить элемент ?

Comment: `$(".prod-img").remove();` Вас по какой-то конкретной причине не устраивает? или нет? просто `$(".prod-img video").remove();` должен удалить тег видео, а див с классом оставить нетронутым

Comment: я попробовал - все работает https://jsfiddle.net/r1tmrya7/1/ если закомментировать js, то впролне можно посмотреть видео, а если оставить, ничего нет

Comment: если необходимо удалить тэг video, то все и так ок. если проблема и есть (т.е. тэг остается на странице), то не в привиденных кусках кода.

Comment: @NumminorihSF мы с вами уже друг друга убедили, что всё хорошо. дело за автором :)

Comment: Да, похоже был какой-то глюк. Сейчас все работает.

Comment: @ThomasSpring, если "вопрос решен", пожалуйста, примите какой-либо ответ, либо напишите свой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Всё работает](https://jsfiddle.net/yyyb7a9u/):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="$('.prod-img video').remove();">Удалить</button>

<div class="prod-img" style="background-image: none;">
  <video controls="">
    <source src="http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/H264/Talkinghead_Media/H264_test1_Talkinghead_mp4_480x360.mp4" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>
</div>
```

Возможно у вас их несколько и удаляется не тот или возникает ошибка, посмотрите консоль через "Инструменты разработчика"

Answer (score 0):

`$(".prod-img video").remove();` в данном случае должен удалить тэг видео, который находится внутри чего-либо с классом `.prod-img`. Чтобы удалить весь тэг с данным классом достаточно `$(".prod-img").remove();`. Конкретнее про селекторы можно почитать например [тут](https://webref.ru/css) (якоря нет, поэтому придется вручную "домотать" до раздела "Селекторы").